# Iterate through nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like

```
{
"Date":{"0":"30-April-2018","1":"27-April-2018","2":"26-April-2018"},
"Open Price":{"0":15.75,"1":16.8,"2":17.5},
"High Price":{"0":15.85,"1":17.0,"2":17.5},
"Low Price":{"0":14.65,"1":15.6,"2":16.35}
}
```

I want to iterate through all the outer keys such as `Date`, `Open Price` to create table headers and then iterate through inner elements to create rows. I have already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object), but what it does is iterate through each and every value, even `Date` is iterated as `D`, `a`, `t`, `e`. Is it possible or is there any other way I can make a table from javascript object.

Comment: `I have already tried this answer, but what it does is iterate through each and every value, even Date is iterated as D, a, t, e.` you did it wrong ... show what you've done

Comment: I passed the javascript object as it is to the functions, but each one is giving me the same output.

Comment: right ... that sentence doesn't look like javascript, sounds like a vague description of something ... StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys. This will return all headers.

You can use `Object.values` to get all the values, use `reduce` to summarise your data.

```js
let obj = {"Date":{"0":"30-April-2018","1":"27-April-2018","2":"26-April-2018"},"Open Price":{"0":15.75,"1":16.8,"2":17.5},"High Price":{"0":15.85,"1":17.0,"2":17.5},"Low Price":{"0":14.65,"1":15.6,"2":16.35}}

let headers = Object.keys(obj);

let content = Object.values(Object.values(obj).reduce((c, v) => {
  Object.entries(v).map(([i, o]) => {
    c[i] = c[i] || [];
    c[i].push(o);
  });
  return c;
}, {}));


console.log(headers);
 
//Every array element of content will a row on the table
//Loop content as
content.forEach(o=>console.log(o));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following

```js
var obj = {
"Date":{"0":"30-April-2018","1":"27-April-2018","2":"26-April-2018"},
"Open Price":{"0":15.75,"1":16.8,"2":17.5},
"High Price":{"0":15.85,"1":17.0,"2":17.5},
"Low Price":{"0":14.65,"1":15.6,"2":16.35}
};

var headers = Object.keys(obj); // get the header row

var rows = []; // this will be collection of data

// get the values and iterate over them
Object.values(obj).forEach((item) => { 
 // iterate over every value in the object and push it in array
  Object.values(item).forEach((val, index) => {
    rows[index] = rows[index] || [];
    rows[index].push(val); 
  });
});

console.log(headers);
console.log(rows);
```